# Firebase target users based on the imported segments

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

I would like to send in-app and cloud messages to a group of users based on non-standard criteria.
I decided to link firebase project with BigQuery and use imported segments to accomplish this task.
The problem is that fcm message composer always target 0 users when i filter users based on the segment.

I added such entry to the SegmentMetadata table

```
{
    "segment_label": "test_segment_label",
    "display_name": "test_display_name_metadata"
  }
```

and such entry to the SegmentMemberships table

```
{
    "instance_id": my device fcm token,
    "segment_labels": [
      "test_segment_label"
    ],
    "update_time": null,
    "membership_name": "test"
  }
```

Now on the firebase console when i am trying to send cloud message and target users based on this segment i see that 0 users are matched, do you have any idea why?
[image snapshot from firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqbb6.png)

(my device fcm token that i putted on the entry in the SegmentMemberships table should be valid because i see on android studio logs that it doesn't change)

Comment: The most obvious answer is that the imported segment has no members and I don't see that you've ruled that out here. Also check that you [enabled the import](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/import-segments#enable_bigquery_import) and that you've waited the required 12 hours for data to be imported.

Comment: Note that when imported segments have members they show up in the expanded dropdown as demonstrated in the screenshot [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/import-segments#use_imported_segments)

Comment: strange, now i think i waited more than 12 hours, i have firebase project connected with bigquery, also several times i manually clicked import segments button on firebase console to be sure that data is synced...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instance_id` is not your fcm token but the part before colon in your token.
When you call `getToken()` in SDK the token returned is in this format: `<instance_id>:<token>`

Comment: yes, I forgot to update this topic but this was the source of my problem.